# How to remove gray color from the webview?

Tags: iphone

I have loaded pdf file in `uiwebview`. But in `webview` its show gray color. I have tried to remove gray color, but without any success. I have used [UIColor clearcolor]. But that is not working. Can you give me idea how to remove gray color from the UIwebview?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background of the webview to white color instead of clearcolor...

Comment: I have applied white color but its show grey shadow color.How to remove shadow color. SV,RR,MD

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `yourWebview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];`
Hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the WebView to transparent, just type this `android:alpha="0"` between the `WebView` tags.